# Dynamically resizing HTML emails

Tags: html, html-email

I'm writing an HTML email which functions perfectly well in the browser. But I've just been sending it by copying what's in the browser window and pasting it into the mail app on my computer and sending it that way. This doesn't do a lot of the things I want it to like resizing with the window and staying centered in the page.

How do big companies send HTML emails? because the positioning always works in a lot of the emails I get from them.

Comment: You can try mailchimp or something similar

Comment: they use responsive design. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Answer (score 0):

First HTML emails rely on tables so make sure you are coding your email using a table structure and not coding it how you would a normal webpage. Second make sure all your CSS is inline. Third you can send your emails using email automation services like [MailChimp](https://mailchimp.com/), Marketo, Constant Contact, GetResponse, etc.

If you want to send yourself a test email you could use a service like [PutsMail](https://putsmail.com/) for free.

You might also try following [this tutorial](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-future-proof-responsive-email-without-media-queries--cms-23919) to help you with creating a responsive email template.

Answer (score 0):

Rule 1: Code like it's 1999 and use tables.

Rule 2: On all tables, set "width:100%; max-width: 600px;margin:auto;". You can replace the max-width with any value you want. The first two properties will make sure that the email fits the width of mobile devices. The second property will keep it centered.

There are a lot more rules and exceptions to the rules, but these are some good basics to start with when it comes to responsive design.